# Error in webBrowser1.InvokeScript

Tags: c#, wpf, com, tinymce

I am loading a html webpage having TinyMCE editor inside the WebBrowser control of WPF. You can get the idea bu looking below screen shot:
[output snapshot](http://s8.postimage.org/aleydu1n9/output.png)

To access text typed in TinyMCE in raw html format, I have written this javascript function in html page:

```
 function getContent() {
    return tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent();
 }
```

I call this function on WPF button click as follows:

```
    string editHtml = this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("getContent").ToString();
```

And editHtml grabs the html of text entered in TinyMCE as desired.
Now I want to set the html of the tinyMCE in the webpage through the C# code.

So for that I wrote javascript function on html page:

```
function setContent(strcontent) {
    return tinyMCE.get('elm1').setContent(strcontent);
}
```

I tried calling this function on WPF button click as follows:

```
string setHtml = this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("setContent('tempinfo')").ToString();
```

But now I am getting an err as follows:
[error snapshot](http://s16.postimage.org/g7ra8rnph/err.png)

Please note the small button below the tinymce in WebBrowser control in 1rst diagram.
It calls the same setContent() as follows:

```
<input type="button" onmousedown="setContent('tempinfo')" />
```

and this sets the tinymce content to text: tempinfo - as desired.
So why the error occurs when calling through the WPF button click?

Comment: both setContent() and getContent() are tinyMCE api functions: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent                  and http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake in above code is that the InvokeScript accepts only method name - no brackets:

```
string setHtml = this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("setContent").ToString();
```

Next I should pass the param by using

```
WebBrowser.InvokeScript Method (String, Object)
```

[see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443.aspx)

So my call now looks like this:

```
this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("setContent","Just done").ToString();
```